# V-if on a component props

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js

I am defining a template as follow :

```
Vue.component('card', {
   props: ['id','image','title','date', 'category'],
   template: `
   <a :href="link">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-image">
        <figure class="image is-4by3">
          <img :src="image" alt="Placeholder image">
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
        <div class="content">
            {{title}}
          <br>
          <time>{{date}}</time>
        </div>
       </div>   
    </div>
   </a>
   `,
   computed: {
    link: function (){
        return "/article.php?id=" + this.id
    }
   }
})

new Vue ({
  el: '#root',
  data: {
    selected: '',   
  },
})
```

And using in in my php file :

```
echo '<div class="column">
 <card id="'.$articles[$index]['id'].'" image="'.$articles[$index]['image'].'" category="'.$articles[$index]['category'].'" title="'.$articles[$index]['title'].'" date="'. date("F j, Y, g:i a",strtotime($articles[$index]['date'])).'">
 </card>
 </div>';
```

And I would like to v-if property category from the card == property selected from the view.
I have tried putting the v-if everywhere, in the php, in the template, I have also tried defining category as a reactive property but nothing looks to be suitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call v-if on the parent component

```php
echo '<div class="column">
 <card v-if="!selected || selected === '."'".$articles[$index]['category']."'"." id="'.$articles[$index]['id'].'" image="'.$articles[$index]['image'].'" category="'.$articles[$index]['category'].'" title="'.$articles[$index]['title'].'" date="'. date("F j, Y, g:i a",strtotime($articles[$index]['date'])).'">
 </card>
 </div>';
```

```
new Vue ({
  el: '#root',
  data: {
    selected: 'someInitialValue',   
  },
})
```

Comment: It is not working, nothing is appearring. I think because selected is an empty value when the rendering is done

Comment: That makes sense, you would have to set it to a default value in your data property

Comment: But doesn't that mean that only the items with the category id same as my default value will be generated ?

Comment: You could also do `v-if="!selected || selected === '."'".$articles[$index]['category']."'"`